# Let me set the defualt window size!

Tags: windows

It's really irritating when people block me from making My PC do what I want! IE: Microsoft, google, any mobile device and now TOR!

I know the security concerns and "I" still want the browser to open in same size window of my choice every time I start it.

The following config integers,

"extensions.torbutton.window.innerHeight" and
"extensions.torbutton.window.innerWidth"

No longer function since the last update.

Please tell me how to FORCE the program to open in a 1200x1000 window when started.

Please do not explain anything I have not specifically asked about.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - Tor Button is no longer responsible for setting the window size.

[Tor Browser 6.5 Release](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-65-released)

> We moved a lot of Torbutton's privacy settings directly into the respective Firefox menu making it cleaner and more straightforward to use. Finally, we moved as many Torbutton features as possible into Firefox to make it easier for upstreaming them. This allowed us to resolve a couple of window resizing bugs that piled on over the course of the past years.

[#21322](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21322)

> ...there is `privacy.window.maxInnerWidth` and `privacy.window.maxInnerHeight` you can set...

Also be sure to untick the "Change details that distinguish you from other Tor Browser users" box to ensure that you're fingerprintable.

Essentially the stuff was moved from the Tor Button extension into Firefox itself, to sort some problems with trying to use an extension to enforce it and to make it easier for them to be pushed upstream to Firefox.